# vimscript: No match error

Tags: vimscript, vimgrep

I'm trying to write a vim-script function, which allows me to `grep` the word under cursor easily in my project.

```
function! CustomGrep()
    vimgrep expand("<cword>") **/*.h **/*.hpp **/*.c **/*.cpp
endfunction
```

However, when I executed `:call CustomGrep()` in my vim, I got an error:

```
E480: No match: expand("<cword>")
```

Did I do something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `<cword>` directly here:

```
function! CustomGrep()
    vimgrep <cword> **/*.h **/*.hpp **/*.c **/*.cpp
endfunction
```

If you look up `:help <cword>` you'll see it's on a section about ["Ex special characters"](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html?#cmdline-special), which also cover special characters you might be familiar with, such as `%` and `#` (as in, `:e #`, to edit the alternate buffer.)

That section also mentions (a little above `<cword>`) that:

> These can also be used in the expression
>   function `expand()`.

In other words, they're primarily meant to be used *directly* in Ex commands, and only available through `expand()` for the cases where you actually need them as a string.

Comment: It's hard to predict how a `:vim` command including special characters in its pattern will be parsed without delimiters. While your cursor is on the `x` in the text `foo !x!bar`, run `:vim <cWORD> %`. Instead of looking for `!x!bar` in the current file, Vim looks for `x` in the file `bar` and in the current file. More generally, the expansion may be parsed as anything: a delimiter, a flag, or a filename. The same issue can affect `<cword>`. That's why I always use delimiters. But inside delimiters, Vim stops expanding special characters, so you need `expand()` and `:exe`.

Comment: Small other nitpick: `expand()` is not only useful to get a string, but also to force Vim to expand special characters earlier. Run this command while your cursor is on `a'b`: `:setl gp&vim | 4verb exe 'grep '..shellescape('<cWORD>')`; it fails, because the shell runs `grep -n 'a'b' ...`. And yet you've used `shellescape()`.

Comment: The issue is not that `shellescape()` did not receive a valid string; if that was the case, then it would have raised E116 (try `:echo shellescape('a'b')`). The issue is that `shellescape()` was evaluated *before* `<cWORD>` was expanded. So, it didn't have any effect. `expand()` fixes the issue by forcing Vim to expand the special characters *during* the expressions evaluation step (and not after): `:setl gp&vim | 4verb exe 'grep '..shellescape(expand('<cWORD>'))`.

Answer (score 2):

> Did I do something wrong here?

`:vimgrep` is a command which takes a string. `expand()` is a function call. You must use `execute` then:

```
execute 'vimgrep' expand('<cword>') '**/*.h ...'
```